# Is it possible to use 2 VPN connections on MacOS simultaneously and route traffic through connections based on hosts?

Tags: macos, vpn, routing, openvpn

I use MacOS and I want to use 2 VPN connections simultaneously and route traffic through connection based on hosts.

Traffic to hosts example1.xxx and example2.xxx should be routed through first_connection and all other traffic should be routed through second_connection.

How can I achieve this? My client is OpenVPN Connect and it can not establish 2 connections simultaneously.